# How to execute returned response Javascript when scraping a site?

Tags: javascript, python, cookies, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm scraping a site that throws the following error when I try to scrape it using Scrapy: 
[image]

After debugging it for a while I figured out that the page returned has inline Javascript code that generates a unique cookie (generated with a pretty complex mechanism that is encoded in the HTML and then decoded using Javascript and run). After setting the cookie the page refreshes using `window.location.reload(true)`, the cookie is sent and I get back the desired page.

However, since I can't run the `<script>` tags inside the HTML response I can't get the unique cookie value.

Has anyone encountered something like this? What can I do to solve this?

Comment: yes, this is very common, your alternatives are to figure out how to replicate that cookie and add it yourself in scrapy headers, or to use a browser emulator like `selenium` or [`splash`](https://github.com/scrapinghub/splash)

Comment: Ok great. And will they enable me to read the cookie value / return it to the python script?

Comment: You can also rewrite that piece of code in python inside of your script if it's simple enough. You can also pipe that code to node.js or any other javascript interpreter with `subprocess` module.

Comment: What if I can't since it's DOM related?